# Devise after_sign_in_path error: Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm following the Devise wiki to redirect the user to the current page after signing in ([https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update))

However I'm getting the following error:

```
Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-12 18:52:52 -0300
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  ←[1m←[35mUser Load (3.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 3 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/login
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
```

This is the code I have on my Application Controller:

```
  after_filter :store_location

  def store_location
    # store last url - this is needed for post-login redirect to whatever the user last visited.
    if (request.fullpath != "/users/sign_in" &&
        request.fullpath != "/users/sign_up" &&
        request.fullpath != "/users/password" &&
        !request.fullpath.match("/users") &&
        !request.xhr? && # don't store ajax calls
        request.format == "text/html" || request.content_type == "text/html")
      session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath 
      session[:last_request_time] = Time.now.utc.to_i
    end
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    session[:previous_url] || root_path
  end
```

Any idea why this is happening? Thanks

**routes.rb**

```
Myapp::Application.routes.draw do
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks", :registrations => "registrations" }, :skip => [:sessions] 
  as :user do
    get 'login' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    post 'login' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
    delete 'logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
  end

  root  'static_pages#home'
```

**devise.rb**

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.secret_key = ENV['DEVISE_SECRET_KEY']

  require 'devise/orm/active_record'

  # omniauth login
  require "omniauth-facebook"
  config.omniauth :facebook, ENV["APP_ID"], ENV["APP_SECRET"],
      {:scope => 'email, offline_access, user_events, friends_events', :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => '/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'}}} 

  # add username to login
  config.authentication_keys = [ :login ]
  config.reset_password_keys = [ :email ]
  config.confirmation_keys = [ :login ]

  config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]

  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email ]

  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]

  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10

  config.reconfirmable = false

  config.password_length = 8..128

  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours

  config.sign_out_via = :delete
end
```

Comment: Can you post your `routes.rb` and `devise.rb` files?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your session[:previous_url] store fullpath and fullpath is everything after `/` which mean you try to redirect to /users for example that why you get the error and your other condition will never be executed because fullpath never be nil.

try to store in your session[:previous_url] `"#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{request.fullpath}"` OR `request.original_url`
and it will solve you problem for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the help. From what I understood you meant doing this: `session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath ` to `session[:previous_url] = "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{request.fullpath}"`. I tried this and it didn't work.